# Python 3.5.2 "takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program in python that connects to a mysql database and can access it and manipulate it. I am using PyMySQL in order to do this however I am stumped by this error that keeps occuring in my program. Here is the error:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE ? = ?", record, recordtype)
TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

But I see no error in my code (may be being a bit confident).

```
def findbooking():
   recordtype =  input("Which field do you want to search?: ")
   record = input("Enter what you want to search: ")
   findbookingsql(record, recordtype)

def findbookingsql(record, recordtype):  #Connect to Database and find record specified
    conn = sql.connect(server,user, password,database)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE ? = ?",recordtype,record)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return row
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encapsulate the parameters in a tuple, rather than stand alone arguments:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE ? = ?", (record, recordtype))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sqlite3.Connection.execute`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute) (and also for similar methods on other Connection classes) take up to 3 parameters:

- The first is `self`, you call it on an instance: `cursor` so that one is passed implicitly and automatically.
- The second is `sql` that seems correct.
- The third is optional `parameters` that's where it goes wrong. What is your `record` and `recordtype`? Did you mean to pass them in as sequence?

  ```
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE ? = ?", 
                 [recordtype, record])
  ```